# Why does #0[[1]] &[] output 0?

Tags: pure-function

When a pure function accesses the first element of itself, 0 is output. What is the logic behind this, or is there any?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FullForm` of `#0[[1]] &` is

```
Function[Part[Slot[0], 1]]
```

So when this function is called with no arguments, I believe what happens is that `Slot[0]` does not evaluate, and then you take the first part of `Slot`, which is 0. Here it seems that `Slot` behaves as any other head.

Comment: No need to believe, you can check :) `#0[[1]] &[] // Trace`